# difference between elixir phoenix and laravel elixir

Tags: laravel, elixir, phoenix-framework, laravel-elixir

I have used the Laravel PHP Framework for web development, and I now want to learn about elixir and to use this as a REST API service.

My question is: what is the difference between elixir phoenix and laravel elixir?

Comment: The only thing they have in common is the name. There's nothing else common between the two of them.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed unless it's a duplicate - the mistake seems easy enough to make?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/) is a web framework written in [the Elixir programming language](http://elixir-lang.org/). It has nothing to do with laravel or its elixir.

[Laravel's elixir](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir) is a [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) app that is built on top of [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to provide an easy way to manage your client-side assets (minification/concatentation/transformation/versioning etc.)

The two have absolutely nothing in common.